# Monomial into power sum

Tags: combinatorics

This might be a routine problem but I'm unable to express monomial symmetric functions $m_\lambda$ into power sum symmetric functions $p_\mu$'s. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: I believe you're looking for [Newton's identities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)?

Comment: @Jakobian I don't see where monomial symmetric functions are expressed in terms of power sum symmetric functions.

Comment: Explaining more instead of acting mysterious would help

Comment: @Jakobian I'm sorry I don't understand what's mysterious here. I can't find an expression of monomial symmetric functions in terms of power sum symmetric functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a formula, but it is not pretty. See [Mike Zabrocki's symmetric function notes](https://garsia.math.yorku.ca/ghana03/chapters/mainfile3.pdf), page 38. The definition of $z_\lambda$ is elsewhere, I believe it is $z_\lambda=1^{m_i}m_i!\cdot 2^{m_2}m_2!\cdots$, where $m_i$ is the multiplicity of $i$. They reference a chapter not in that document for an idea of the proof, but it is included [here](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/19079932/introduction-to-symmetric-functions-mike-zabrocki), page 43=44.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for and yes, it's not pretty. :)

Answer (score 0):

In MacDonald's $\textit{Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials}$,
Chapter I, Section 6 discusses all cases between the fundamental
bases for symmetric functions. Included is a complete Table
based on Kostka numbers and related matrices.